# Maximal number of commuting functions of a finite set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a finite set with $n$ elements and let $F_S$ denote the set of functions from $S$ to $S$. I wonder whether anything is known about the maximal cardinality of a commuting subset of $F_S$? A simple construction gives $2^{n-1}$ commuting elements, but I have no idea if this could be close to optimal. Is there any relevant literature?

Comment: You could send half the base set to a distinguished element and send the other half to the first half.  This would give (n/2)^(n/2) elements.  Gerhard "And Maybe There Are More" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: Very true... Thanks for this observation. I guess if you split the space differently, you could get $(n/\log n)^{(1-1/\log n)n}$, which is something like $e^{n\log n-n\log\log n}$.

Comment: $2^{n-1}$ is known to be the largest size of a set of commuting idempotent maps.  I would Google maximal commutative subsemigroups of full transformation semigroups. I didn't find a precise reference that way, just a to appear that never appeared

Comment: According to the open questions at the end of  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669810001265 this is open.

Comment: Gerhard's construction is building a null subsemigroup (the product of any two elements is the same). I guess one should be able to find the maximum size of a subsemigroup of this sort fromhttps://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-219-00/S0002-9947-1976-0404502-4/S0002-9947-1976-0404502-4.pdf but it might be annoying to extract

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thanks very much for this info! Also glad to hear that my guess, while far from the mark, is the answer to something!

Comment: Presumably you are associating to each subset of {1,...n-1} the mapping which fixes that subset and send the complement to n.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: yes, exactly.